# Responsivefilemanager TinyMCE Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I am trying to use [Responsivefilemanager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/#download-section) for managing files on the server with TinyMCE 4.6.7. So far, file uploads are working. I can upload and browse files/folders, but when I click an image to insert it into the text editor, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: parent.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams(...).setUrl is not a function
at apply_any (include.js?v=9.12.1:1)
at apply_img (include.js?v=9.12.1:1)
at a (include.js?v=9.12.1:1)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (include.js?v=9.12.1:1)
at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
at HTMLUListElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4338)
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out I was using the wrong button. To insert images from responsivefilemanager, you need to use the responsivefilemanager button (green) instead of the image/media toolbar buttons (red)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you assist? I do not see the green button.

Comment: You need to add "responsivefilemanager" to the toolbar in tinymce.init(). Read more here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/